# stormdist of Storm can be deleted?

Tags: apache-storm

When existing topology is deployed with new deployment(prior to this topology has been killed using Storm UI) in 'Clustered Environment', topology is not responding.

when all contents of "stormdist" folder has been removed and restarted supervisor, topology start responding.

Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: What do you mean by "Clustered Environment" ? I am also wondering why you want to deploy the same topology twice?

Comment: @Jagrut Dalwadi : new deployment in  "Clustered Environment" ... you mean you did some changes to existing topology and redeployed again in the same cluster? pls. mention Storm version and the environment details.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. clustered environment means Strom clustered environment where zookeepers,nimbus and workers deployed on different clusters. we are using 0.9.5 version. I am talking about undeploying topology using storm ui/command and again deploying.